# Type 'null' is not assignable to type '() => void | null'

Tags: typescript

I basically understand *TS2322*, but in this case, I don't get it.

I have a given class definition like this:

```
export class MyFaultyClass {
  functionOrNull: () => void | null;

  constructor() {
    this.functionOrNull = null; // <- here comes the error TS2322
  }
}
```

**My question**

Why can't I assign null to the defined property?

**My expectation**

```
constructor() {
  this.functionOrNull = null; // OR
  this.functionOrNull = () => {};
}
```

**Edit**

Here is a "working" example: [typescriptlang.org/playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20MyFaultyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20functionOrNull%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.functionOrNull%20%3D%20null%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C-%20here%20comes%20the%20error%20TS2322%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)
Needs strictNullChecks to be enabled.

Comment: Ahh, "any" type, true friend, there forever, til the end...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's the fix, then the explanation:

```
export class MyWorkingClass {
    functionOrNull: { () : void } | null;

  constructor() {
    this.functionOrNull = null; // <- Joy
  }
}
```

So when you say `() => void | null` the function will return either `void` or `null`.

When you say `{ () : void } | null;` it is either a function returning `void`, or it is null.

Comment: `functionOrNull: (() => void) | null;` should work too

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir is does.

Comment: Based on this, mine worked by using parenthesis instead of the curly braces around the `() => void`. But that's probably my TSLinter..